# How to update MYSQL Database with data from Excel using ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, mysql, asp.net-mvc, excel, windows-services

I have an excel file which gets updated every 10 seconds through an automated process. I need excel data to be updated in MY-SQL database which is located on a remote server.

How do I do that?

I have thought of following option:
1) Every 11 seconds, an Excel macro will run and will "Save as" excel as CSV file. (not sure whether this can be done by macro...just thinking)
2) This CSV file we will FTP to remote server using Windows Service.
3) On remote server, we will parse the csv file and Update MYSQL database.

Is this approach fine? Or do you have a better approach which requires less time to update the database?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have any options to modify the automated process with the excel file?

Comment: @Mellamokb, Excel basically fetches data from a third party server...so what options do you think we should modify in that excel?

Comment: For instance, can your remote server with MySql query the same third-party server directly, instead of passing through with Excel file.

Comment: That's a good idea. But unfortunately no. That third party service has an Excel plugin. So they only allow data access thru Excel :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found following links to be more useful:

http://www.heritage-tech.net/908/inserting-data-into-mysql-from-excel-using-vba/

http://vbaexcel.eu/vba-macro-code/update-mysql-database-php

I hope this helps someone having similar problem as mine.

Answer (score 0):

You can connect to the Excel spreadsheet using `ODBC` connection, read the data, and post it to the `MySQL` database, maybe through some sort of web service access, or via a saved CSV file?