# Importing data from excel to MYSQL database tables through c# code (Asp.net) by Uploading it through UI

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to import the data from xls to my MYSQL database,but problem is that the data/columns present in xls file is from different number of tables.
Suppose we have column col1,col2,col3,col4,col5,col6 from xls. col1,col3 from table1 and col2,col4 from table2 and col5,col6 from table3

How can i import these all columns field data to those corresponding tables through c# code?

Comment: it is called mapping.

Comment: Maybe you can refer to this [topic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5189930/how-to-update-mysql-database-with-data-from-excel-using-asp-net)

Comment: We can say it is mapping,but i want to insert those cols to proper table to which it belongs. and also the cols there in xls are having alias for some col lets suppose for col1 will be displayed in xls as column1 it should go to table1 as col1. thanx